# Chrome page jumpes/flickering when hidden content showing and scroll down

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have layout like this:

```
<div class="fixed scroll"> //div with position fixed and scroll
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item hover"> //div on hover showing hidden
    <div class="hidden"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when hover last div and scroll down when showing hidden div, the page starts jumping/flickering (only in google chrome).

Show issue on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Yaolegol/pen/poyYbvV)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add for div with fixed and scroll style

```
overflow-anchor: none;
```

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/Yaolegol/pen/poyYbvV)

See more on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring)